# how to get all possible combinations from array which contains all elements of another array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an array containing unique numbers like `[2,3,4]`.
I have another array which contains some numbers including duplicates like `a2 = [1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5,6,7]`

I want all possible combinations from array-2 which has all values of array-1
like `[a2[1],a2[3],a2[4]]`,`[a2[2],a2[3],a2[4]]` etc.

Comment: Tried anything yet ?

Comment: not able to start the logic yet

Comment: This looks like a subsequence problem. You should tag algorithms instead of java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a recursion. I have coded something which leads you to the correct direction. It perhaps works, but I didn't test it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a1 = new int[]{2,3,4};
        int[] a2 = new int[]{1,2,2,3,4,4,3,5,6,7};
        recursion(a1,a2, new String());
    }

    public static void recursion(int[] a1, int[] a2, String soFar){
        int toSearch = a1[0];
        for(int i=0;i<a2.length;i++){
            if(a2[i] == toSearch){
                if(a1.length>1) {
                    int[] a1b = new int[a1.length - 1];
                    for (int j = 1; j < a1.length; j++) {
                        a1b[j - 1] = a1[j];
                    }
                    recursion(a1b, a2, soFar+ "a2["+i+"]");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(soFar+ "a2["+i+"]");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
    a2[1]a2[3]a2[4]
    a2[1]a2[3]a2[5]
    a2[1]a2[6]a2[4]
    a2[1]a2[6]a2[5]
    a2[2]a2[3]a2[4]
    a2[2]a2[3]a2[5]
    a2[2]a2[6]a2[4]
    a2[2]a2[6]a2[5]
```

Comment: Nice to know:) Then please upvote my answer and mark it as correct answer. Thanks!